# Cycle numbers of array with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, cycle

I'm trying to cycle an array similar to this with JavaScript. arr0=[0,1,2,3] I want to cycle the last number in the array to the first index and continue to cycle through the array numbers. I tried to use an interval and shift push and pop but I can't make the array cycle.

```js
outArr0 = [0, 1, 2, 3];
var cou0 = -1;
var int0 = setInterval(function() {
  cou0++

  var pushThis0 = outArr0[outArr0.length - 1];
  outArr0.pop();
  outArr0.shift();
  outArr0[0] = pushThis0;
  console.log(outArr0);

  if (cou0 == 6) {
    clearInterval(int0)
  }
}, 500);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check following code, just fixed your codes,

```js
outArr0 = [0, 1, 2, 3];
var cou0 = -1;
var int0 = setInterval(function() {
  cou0++
  console.log(outArr0[0]);
  outArr0.push(outArr0.shift());
  //

  if (cou0 == 6) {
    clearInterval(int0)
  }
}, 500);
```

Answer (score 0):

To cycle you just need an index that will reset if it reaches the end of the array's length. You can use modulo operator to achieve this.

```js
function cycle() {
  let index = 0;
  let arr = [0,1,2,3];
  return function() {
    console.log(arr[index++ % (arr.length)]);
  }
}

setInterval(cycle(), 500);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you cycle backwards through the elements...

```
  var outArr = [0, 1, 2, 3];

  for (i = outArr.length; i!=-1; i--){
    console.log(outArr[i]);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, I believe this will help
I've added comments for clarity.

```
//define a function to cycle the array
function cycleArray(theArray)
{
    //store the last value in the array
    var _tmp = theArray[theArray.length-1];
    //iterate from last to first element, pulling the element from the prev. index
    for(i = theArray.length-1; i > 0; i--)
    {
        theArray[i] = theArray[i-1];
    }
    //place the saved last element into the first slot of the array
    theArray[0] = _tmp;
}
```

How to use the function:

```
//define your array
someArray = [0, 1, 2, 3];

alert(someArray.toString());

//cycle the array
cycleArray(someArray);

alert(someArray.toString());
```

The above code produces the following:

> 0,1,2,3
>
> 3,0,1,2

Nice and simple. I hope I have understood your question correctly.